# VBA - Vba Formula, Auto Calculating

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a function that calculates if the cell is Bold or Not

I have entered the function name '=énegrito' in the cell and the function provides me with the desired result

I have however a number of rows and would like it to update when any changes are made automatically

I have Auto Calculate on - which works for formulas, but doesnt seem to work for a vba function
Already tried Application.Volatile and it doesnt work

```
Function énegrito(ByVal vCel As Range) As String
Dim c As String
Application.Volatile
If vCel.Font.Bold = True Then
   c = True
   ActiveSheet.Calculate
Else
   c = False
   ActiveSheet.Calculate
End If
énegrito = c

End Function
```

Is there any other thing i can try?

Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Marking a cell bold or not does not trigger a recalculation. Formatting should ideally *reflect* data, not be used *as* data.

Comment: I see, but i need to check the format of the cell. Do you think there is a better way of doing it?  thanks anyway

Comment: Why is the format of the cell important? What does it reflect?

Comment: Because i use it in another formula, it works fine but i always have to refresh the excel every time i make any changes to make it works

Comment: If you're using `Conditional Formatting` to get the bold formatting, please share the formula.